# I'am trying to implement BFS and count all the visited node through the edges. But my code giving me 0 count except the 1st one

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

In this code I just want to visit the node and count the edges. For the 1st time it seems good but when I pass new nodes and edges it is giving 0 count. I find out that it's  condition is not true for the next nodes and edges. It's my first implementation of BFS.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int>v[1000];
int level[1000];
bool vis[1000];
void bfs(int s,int E)
{
int count=0;
queue<int>q;
q.push(s);
level[s]=0;
vis[s]=true;
while(!q.empty())
{
    int p=q.front();
    q.pop();
    for(int i=0;i<v[p].size();i++)
    {
        if(vis[v[p][i]] == false)
        {
            level[v[p][i]] = level[p]+1;
            q.push(v[p][i]);
            vis[v[p][i]] = true;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
cout<<count<<endl;
}

int main()
{
int N,E,x,y,size;
while(scanf("%d %d",&N,&E)==2)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=E;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        v[x].push_back(y);
        v[y].push_back(x);
    }
    int s=0;
    bfs(s);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not resetting whatever variables you have used like your adjacency list `v`,`level` and `vis`.

You have to reset them to some default value before working on a different graph, as values of previous graphs are unwanted.

You can simply run a loop, before each input:

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    v[i].clear();
    vis[i]=0;
    level[i]=-1;
}
```